How to set the checkbox column of a datagridview to true based on the available values in the database
I have a datagridview with three columns. The third column is a checkbox column. Initially all checked values are inserted in the database (can have multiple checked values) based on the id. I have a button to update data. For this, all previous saved data has to be checked in the checkbox column as per the Id. My question is: How to check all values in the database in the datagridview checkbox columns based on the Id?
I have uploaded a sample of the datagridview and the saved data from the database.
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (productionid1.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter the Production id");
    }    
        string query1 = "Select property_used.Production_Id, property_used.Location_Id, property_used.Property_Id, location.Location_Name from property_used inner join location on property_used.Location_Id = location.Location_Id where property_used.Production_Id = @PI";    

        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query1, con);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@PI", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = productionid1.Text;
        MySqlDataReader reader2;
        reader2 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader2.Read())
        {

            locationid.Text = reader2[1].ToString();
            locationname.Text = reader2[3].ToString();
            
        }
        reader2.Close();
        con.Close();
    
    }
}

#code for datagridview data 
public void news()
{
    ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(GetDataTable());
    ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Select_Property", typeof(bool));
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
private DataTable GetDataTable()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();

    using (var CON = new MySqlConnection("connectionstring"))
    using (var cmd = new  MySqlCommand("Select Property_Name, Property_Id from property", CON))
    using (var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    
    {
        CON.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

    return dt;
}


